# TFS test build slow, hangs on "vstest.console.exe, TcpClientExtensions.MessageLoopAsync: Polling on remoteEndPoint:" for minutes

Tags: tfs, vstest

I have a build definition of about ~250 test cases that have started to run test cases really slow. It runs almost 100 test cases before finally taking ~8 minutes per test case. With over 100 test cases to go at this point, this is not something we can live with.
I managed to get some logging on the server, and once it starts going slow it logs in the diag log:

```
...
9060, 5, 2019/05/03, 09:52:32.127, 179576170847, vstest.console.exe, TestRunRequest:SendTestRunStatsChange: Completed.
...
18356, 5, 2019/05/03, 09:59:27.108, 169578763371, vstest.console.exe, TcpClientExtensions.MessageLoopAsync: Polling on remoteEndPoint: 127.0.0.1:51949 localEndPoint: 127.0.0.1:51948
18356, 5, 2019/05/03, 09:59:28.108, 169581006890, vstest.console.exe, TcpClientExtensions.MessageLoopAsync: Polling on remoteEndPoint: 127.0.0.1:51949 localEndPoint: 127.0.0.1:51948
18356, 5, 2019/05/03, 09:59:29.108, 169583250453, vstest.console.exe, TcpClientExtensions.MessageLoopAsync: Polling on remoteEndPoint: 127.0.0.1:51949 localEndPoint: 127.0.0.1:51948
18356, 5, 2019/05/03, 09:59:30.108, 169585493854, vstest.console.exe, TcpClientExtensions.MessageLoopAsync: Polling on remoteEndPoint: 127.0.0.1:51949 localEndPoint: 127.0.0.1:51948
...
```

And in the host log:

```
...
TpTrace Verbose: 0 : 18304, 9, 2019/05/03, 09:59:28.405, 169581673025, testhost.exe, TcpClientExtensions.MessageLoopAsync: Polling on remoteEndPoint: 127.0.0.1:51948 localEndPoint: 127.0.0.1:51949
TpTrace Verbose: 0 : 18304, 9, 2019/05/03, 09:59:29.405, 169583916411, testhost.exe, TcpClientExtensions.MessageLoopAsync: Polling on remoteEndPoint: 127.0.0.1:51948 localEndPoint: 127.0.0.1:51949
TpTrace Verbose: 0 : 18304, 9, 2019/05/03, 09:59:30.405, 169586159896, testhost.exe, TcpClientExtensions.MessageLoopAsync: Polling on remoteEndPoint: 127.0.0.1:51948 localEndPoint: 127.0.0.1:51949
TpTrace Verbose: 0 : 18304, 9, 2019/05/03, 09:59:30.936, 169587383747, testhost.exe, TcpClientExtensions.MessageLoopAsync: NotifyDataAvailable remoteEndPoint: 127.0.0.1:51948 localEndPoint: 127.0.0.1:51949
TpTrace Error: 0 : 18304, 9, 2019/05/03, 09:59:30.983, 169587459527, testhost.exe, Socket: Message loop: failed to receive message due to socket error System.IO.IOException: Unable to read data from the transport connection: An existing connection was forcibly closed by the remote host. ---> System.Net.Sockets.SocketException: An existing connection was forcibly closed by the remote host
   at System.Net.Sockets.NetworkStream.Read(Byte[] buffer, Int32 offset, Int32 size)
   --- End of inner exception stack trace ---
   at System.Net.Sockets.NetworkStream.Read(Byte[] buffer, Int32 offset, Int32 size)
   at System.IO.Stream.ReadByte()
   at System.IO.BinaryReader.ReadByte()
   at System.IO.BinaryReader.Read7BitEncodedInt()
   at System.IO.BinaryReader.ReadString()
   at Microsoft.VisualStudio.TestPlatform.CommunicationUtilities.LengthPrefixCommunicationChannel.NotifyDataAvailable()
   at Microsoft.VisualStudio.TestPlatform.CommunicationUtilities.TcpClientExtensions.MessageLoopAsync(TcpClient client, ICommunicationChannel channel, Action`1 errorHandler, CancellationToken cancellationToken), remoteEndPoint: 127.0.0.1:51948 localEndPoint: 127.0.0.1:51949
TpTrace Information: 0 : 18304, 9, 2019/05/03, 09:59:30.983, 169587461935, testhost.exe, SocketClient.PrivateStop: Stop communication from server endpoint: 127.0.0.1:051948, error:System.IO.IOException: Unable to read data from the transport connection: An existing connection was forcibly closed by the remote host. ---> System.Net.Sockets.SocketException: An existing connection was forcibly closed by the remote host
   at System.Net.Sockets.NetworkStream.Read(Byte[] buffer, Int32 offset, Int32 size)
   --- End of inner exception stack trace ---
   at System.Net.Sockets.NetworkStream.Read(Byte[] buffer, Int32 offset, Int32 size)
   at System.IO.Stream.ReadByte()
   at System.IO.BinaryReader.ReadByte()
   at System.IO.BinaryReader.Read7BitEncodedInt()
   at System.IO.BinaryReader.ReadString()
   at Microsoft.VisualStudio.TestPlatform.CommunicationUtilities.LengthPrefixCommunicationChannel.NotifyDataAvailable()
   at Microsoft.VisualStudio.TestPlatform.CommunicationUtilities.TcpClientExtensions.MessageLoopAsync(TcpClient client, ICommunicationChannel channel, Action`1 errorHandler, CancellationToken cancellationToken)
TpTrace Information: 0 : 18304, 28, 2019/05/03, 09:59:30.983, 169587468526, testhost.exe, DefaultEngineInvoker.SetParentProcessExitCallback: ParentProcess '18356' Exited.
TpTrace Verbose: 0 : 18304, 9, 2019/05/03, 09:59:30.983, 169587472928, testhost.exe, LengthPrefixCommunicationChannel.Dispose: Dispose reader and writer.
TpTrace Verbose: 0 : 18304, 9, 2019/05/03, 09:59:30.983, 169587473097, testhost.exe, TcpClientExtensions.MessageLoopAsync: exiting MessageLoopAsync remoteEndPoint: 127.0.0.1:51948 localEndPoint: 127.0.0.1:51949
```

The problem always starts at the same spot, and it doesn't seem to be related to the test cases, I have tried to Ignore some testcases around that time, and it will skip those but stil run into the same problem.

The build server is a Windows 2012 R2 Standard installation, with latest version of Visual studio 2017 enterprise updated (15.9.11).

I've tried to find information about the problem online obviously, and have taken some meassures since;

- Updated visual studio on build machine.
- Changed in build definition to use "VSTest platform installer" build step (with version 16.0.1), and use "Installed by Tools Installer" for the "Test Assemblies"-build step.
- Updated nuget packages MSTest.TestAdapter and MSTest.TestFramework to latest version (2.0.0 beta4)
- vstest.console.exe is version 15.0.0.

I'd gladly provide more information or such as needed...

EDIT:

I can actually only reproduce this problem in Release mode, and it is reproducible even from Visual studio when in release mode, even when running single test case, which suggests other areas of error than I initially thought. When running test case locally, no reporting is done to TFS server, so something else is amiss.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It seems there is a really strange problem with the internal test code, we use MSMQ to ping agents that keep track of the testing environment (system tests), and for some reason, the MSMQ send takes a really long time for certain test cases when built in release mode. If someone sees this because they are looking for an answer to something similar, sorry, I don't even know myself what the actual problem is.